# Earth as a conductor and emf produced?

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, geophysics, conductors

Since about 73% of total surface of Earth is occupied by water, its internal is also occupied largely by hot molten mass.Let,the whole earth is considered a conductor.Sun is a source of gravitational force,lets consider that gravitational field of sun as magnetic field by a magnet(sun).Then,what the emf produced by the motion of conductor(earth) under a magnetic field(gravitational field) called?

Comment: Although the Sun's magnetic field is about 100 times stronger than the Earth's, dipole fields fall off as distance cubed so the Sun's magnetic field is negligable at the Earth. It doesn't make sense to *consider that gravitational field of sun as magnetic field by a magnet* as the gravitational and magnetic fields are completely different in nature, strength and multipole expansion.

Comment: sun`s gravitational field must have some effect on earth as a nucleus have attraction with outer shell electrons of comparatively same size difference,distances at s small scale.No effect at all?

Comment: [Magnetotellurics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetotellurics) is the term used for the geophysical technique used to probe the Earth's electrical properties (crust and mantle.)

Comment: The basic physics and math of magnetotellurics is described [here](http://hendrix2.uoregon.edu/~dlivelyb/LPE_talk/MT_intro.html)